# What's the best way to transform Google Sheets data to an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, performance

I am using Google Spreadsheets as a simple "backend" for a personal web application. Everything is working pretty well, but while developing this code, I had one doubt about performance.

This is not too much relevant to my application, but I wanted to understand what would be the best way to achieve what I did, or if I was actually doing this in a reasonably good fashion.

**The problem:**

Google sheets API returns me something like this as JSON:

```
 "values": [
    [
      "name",
      "country",
      "age"
    ],
    [
      "John",
      "Brazil",
      "21"
    ],
    [
      "Jane",
      "Canada",
      "27"
    ],
   ]
```

But I would prefer to have something like this, in the end:

```
"values": [
{ 
 "name": "John",
 "country": "Brazil",
 "age": "21",
},
{
 "name": "Jane",
 "country": "Canada",
 "age": "27",
}
]
```

This is the code I'm using to make that transformation:

```js
const values = [
  [
    "name",
    "country",
    "age"
  ],
  [
    "John",
    "Brazil",
    "21"
  ],
  [
    "Jane",
    "Canada",
    "27"
  ],
];

const adjustValues = (array) => {
  const indexes = array.shift();
  const returnArray = [];
  array.forEach((value, index) => {
    const returnObject = {};
    value.forEach((column, index) => {
      returnObject[indexes[index]] = column;
    });
    returnArray.push(returnObject);
  });
  return returnArray;
}

console.log(adjustValues(values));
```

Is this a good way to transform that data? What would be the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall, I think your solution makes sense.
However I believe a more Javascript-friendly approach would be to replace both `forEach` by a `map` and a `reduce`.

Here's your function transformed to use `map + reduce` instead of `forEach`:

```
const adjustValues = (array) => {
    const fieldNames = array[0];

    const reducer = (soFar, value, fieldIndex) => {
        soFar[fieldNames[fieldIndex]] = value;
        return soFar
    }
    return array.slice(1).map((row) => {
        return row.reduce(reducer, {})
    });
}
```

Here are some items I've changed from the original function:

1. Used `fieldNames` instead of `indexes`, as `fieldNames` is a better description.
2. Did not use `Array.shift()`, because this function will modify *in place* the parameter that was received. Try printing the parameter before and after calling your function and you'll notice the "headers" disappeared.
3. Leveraged `map` and `reduce` because they explicitly show what's the intention; either *mapping values from an array into another array* or *reducing values from an array into a different structure*.
4. Used `row` instead of `values` to make it clear that I'm reading a "row" from the spreadsheet.

I did not run any performance test or benchmark.

All this being said, I believe your best course of action would be to leverage *streams*. Most likely your spreadsheet reader is receiving a stream or a CSV. If you need to load thousands of records you might end up consuming an insane amount of memory, which could crash your application in case there are concurrent operations.

Basically your process requires twice as much space the original content is. See:

1. You have 10 rows (excluding header)
2. While this data is in memory, you start creating a new object that will have 10 more rows.

Due to this, give a look to the. [`stream-csv-as-json`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-csv-as-json) library. Given the library uses a stream, the CSV content will be read "line by line" and a new object will be created for each line; effectively reducing the memory requirements.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. About the streams, I believe I am not receiving csv or a stream, but a JSON directly from google API: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values?hl=pt-br#ValueRange